# Event value in Android Skin layout?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I've been making some custom skins for my AVD's in Eclipse for Android development and I think I've got the whole layout file worked out except for the "event" parameter in the layouts section.   When I see something like

**event     EV_SW:0:1**

... what does that mean?

Comment: A wild guess; SW stands for south-west. Can't tell about the numbers tho.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it refers to a hardware "switch". The first number is the switch ID, and the second number indicates whether the switch is on or off.

In the case of the emulator, switch number 0 is used to control whether the device is in portrait or landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html#skins) related to creating AVD skins contains a reference to the [Android Emulator Skin File Specification](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/emu-master-dev/docs/ANDROID-SKIN-FILES.TXT)

Within this specification is a section referencing events.  As an example it specifically provides details for EV_SW:0

```
        The typical event to be used is EV_SW:0:1 for portrait mode
        and EV_SW:0:0 for landscape ones. They corresponds to "keyboard
        closed" and "keyboard opened" respectively...
```